# Error while invoking SOAP callout

Tags: apex, soap-api, soap

I am trying to do SOAP integration between two different salesforce orgs.

S1 has a class (FirstAccount) that has been exported as WSDL  and imported into S2 as the following Apex class (soapSforceComSchemasClassFirstaccou).

```
//Actual class from S1 org
    global class FirstAccount
    {

        webservice static String getFirst()
        {

        return ([SELECT ID,Name FROM Account LIMIT 1].Name);

        }

     }
```

//Generated code from S2 org

```
//Generated by wsdl2apex

public class soapSforceComSchemasClassFirstaccou {
    public class LogInfo {
        public String category;
        public String level;
        private String[] category_type_info = new String[]{'category','http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] level_type_info = new String[]{'level','http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'category','level'};
    }
    public class AllowFieldTruncationHeader_element {
        public Boolean allowFieldTruncation;
        private String[] allowFieldTruncation_type_info = new String[]{'allowFieldTruncation','http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'allowFieldTruncation'};
    }
    public class getFirst_element {
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{};
    }
    public class DebuggingHeader_element {
        public soapSforceComSchemasClassFirstaccou.LogInfo[] categories;
        public String debugLevel;
        private String[] categories_type_info = new String[]{'categories','http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount',null,'0','-1','false'};
        private String[] debugLevel_type_info = new String[]{'debugLevel','http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'categories','debugLevel'};
    }
    public class CallOptions_element {
        public String client;
        private String[] client_type_info = new String[]{'client','http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'client'};
    }
    public class location {
        public Double latitude;
        public Double longitude;
        private String[] latitude_type_info = new String[]{'latitude','http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] longitude_type_info = new String[]{'longitude','http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'latitude','longitude'};
    }
    public class address {
        public String city;
        public String country;
        public String countryCode;
        public String postalCode;
        public String state;
        public String stateCode;
        public String street;
        private String[] city_type_info = new String[]{'city','http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] country_type_info = new String[]{'country','http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] countryCode_type_info = new String[]{'countryCode','http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] postalCode_type_info = new String[]{'postalCode','http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] state_type_info = new String[]{'state','http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] stateCode_type_info = new String[]{'stateCode','http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] street_type_info = new String[]{'street','http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'city','country','countryCode','postalCode','state','stateCode','street'};
    }
    public class getFirstResponse_element {
        public String result;
        private String[] result_type_info = new String[]{'result','http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount',null,'1','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'result'};
    }
    public class SessionHeader_element {
        public String sessionId;
        private String[] sessionId_type_info = new String[]{'sessionId','http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'sessionId'};
    }
    public class DebuggingInfo_element {
        public String debugLog;
        private String[] debugLog_type_info = new String[]{'debugLog','http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'debugLog'};
    }
    public class FirstAccount {
        public String endpoint_x = 'https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/Soap/class/FirstAccount';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        public soapSforceComSchemasClassFirstaccou.AllowFieldTruncationHeader_element AllowFieldTruncationHeader;
        public soapSforceComSchemasClassFirstaccou.SessionHeader_element SessionHeader;
        public soapSforceComSchemasClassFirstaccou.CallOptions_element CallOptions;
        public soapSforceComSchemasClassFirstaccou.DebuggingHeader_element DebuggingHeader;
        public soapSforceComSchemasClassFirstaccou.DebuggingInfo_element DebuggingInfo;
        private String AllowFieldTruncationHeader_hns = 'AllowFieldTruncationHeader=http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount';
        private String SessionHeader_hns = 'SessionHeader=http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount';
        private String CallOptions_hns = 'CallOptions=http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount';
        private String DebuggingHeader_hns = 'DebuggingHeader=http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount';
        private String DebuggingInfo_hns = 'DebuggingInfo=http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount';
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount', 'soapSforceComSchemasClassFirstaccou'};
        public String getFirst() {
            soapSforceComSchemasClassFirstaccou.getFirst_element request_x = new soapSforceComSchemasClassFirstaccou.getFirst_element();
            soapSforceComSchemasClassFirstaccou.getFirstResponse_element response_x;
            Map<String, soapSforceComSchemasClassFirstaccou.getFirstResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, soapSforceComSchemasClassFirstaccou.getFirstResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              '',
              'http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount',
              'getFirst',
              'http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/FirstAccount',
              'getFirstResponse',
              'soapSforceComSchemasClassFirstaccou.getFirstResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.result;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to invoke a callout from S2.

I am getting the following error as shown in the screenshot.

The anonymous apex that I tried is as follows :

```
soapSforceComSchemasClassFirstaccou.FirstAccount proxyclass = new soapSforceComSchemasClassFirstaccou.FirstAccount();
String name1 = proxyclass.getFirst();
System.debug(name1);
```

Error is

> System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService
>   returned a SOAP Fault: INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in
>   SessionHeader: Illegal Session faultcode=sf:INVALID_SESSION_ID
>   faultactor=

Screenshot from console

[image]

Question :

Can someone tell me what is the issue and why am I getting that error ?

Comment: Yes, please check the above link by Vamsi. You need to set the sessionheader object and then make the call.

Comment: Just one more thing...I am not using partner or enterprise wsdl of s1 on s2. One of my colleagues mentioned that without importing partner or enterprise wsdl of s1 on s2 I will not be able to do any callouts from s2...is this right ?...PS : We are learning integration for the first time hence the newb questions :)